# Under tmux, change window in Irssi with meta key Alt + Num?

Tags: terminal, command-line, tmux

I think this is specific to OS X Terminal.app

Viewing many windows in irssi via tmux.

I can use `alt`+`right arrow` to move windows as the metakey.

but `alt`+`5` only produces `[KH^`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer moments after posting here.

Apparently, Terminal.app does not escape the `alt` key. It can be turned on in preferences by selectin `Use Option as Meta key`

[image]